# Magento - Product Attribute index and Layered Navigation

Tags: magento

By default Magento's layered navigation logic works as OR - for instance manufacturer is Nike OR Reebok, price is between $80-100 OR between $100-$120, etc.

However there are some multiselect attributes that we want to filter with AND logic - for instance I want to find a tshirt with the color Blue AND Green.

We have the AND logic working...however, there is a problem because the Product Attribute index is building off of the configurable product not the simple products so when I filter tshirts by Blue AND Red I get all configurable tshirts that have a Blue AND Red in any of the simple products, so:

Tshirt 1 (config)
blue and red shirt (simple)

Tshirt 2 (config)
blue shirt (simple)
red shirt (simple)

I get both tshirt 1 and tshirt 2 in my results but really I just want tshirt 1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Am I correct if I think you want to exclude the configurable products from the filters and preform a search on only the simple products?